# Why do changes in DNN are not always visible on all servers in web farm?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Our farm consist of 2 web servers(We use DNN 6.0.2). If admin changes rights on a banner, module or picture, those changes are visible only on server on which that changes were done. On other server changes are not visible until cache cleaning from "Host" menu is invoked .

Is that correct behavior? Did we miss something in web farm configuration?

Comment: Both web servers are pulling from the same database, correct? This feels like a caching problem. I don't have a great answer for you, but I'd try switching the cache settings in "host settings" to see if this behavior changes. I don't have any direct experience with web farms and DNN though.

Comment: Yes, both servers are using same DB and same network drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of individual caching on each web server. DotNetNuke Professional edition has a web request caching provider which handles this.